# Extracting different values from rows in a single cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I have an excel spreadsheet that contains rows in the following format in a single cell.

```
[2013-12-01 00:29:36.45] ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE AUDIT: User [XXXXXX04] logged off.
[2013-12-01 00:29:55.292] ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE AUDIT: User [XXXXX05] authenticated via public key.
[2013-12-01 00:29:55.736] ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE AUDIT: User [xxx03] is opening file [/Inbox/AXS02XXXXXXX.AXS_RECON.IRF7171_EFTDR20131130.txt.p7] for transfer.
[2013-12-01 00:30:02.453] ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE AUDIT: User [xxxx05] authenticated via public key.
[2013-12-01 00:30:35.387] ALL 000000000000 GLOBAL_SCOPE AUDIT: User [sfdsf03] logged off.
```

I want to extract 3 values from only the row containing the word "Inbox". Basically the ouptut i want is as follows,in 3 columns.

eg:-

```
00:29:55   XXXXXX03  AXS02XXXXXXX.AXS_RECON.IRF7171_EFTDR20131130.txt.p7
```

Please note that the username, ie User[x] value is different and of different length for each row.  Please help.

Thank you!

Comment: Is there any code you have tried?  If so, what was the result?  If you have no idea where to start, I'd recommend looking into `For` loops and the `InStr` function.

Answer (score 0):

I am wondering why you need VBA for it, if you have the data already in a Excel sheet. You can also just use the following formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("Inbox";A1));
   "";
   MID(A1;13;8)&" "&
     MID(A1;FIND("User";A1)+6;FIND("]";A1;FIND("User";A1))-FIND("User";A1)-6)&" "&
     MID(A1;FIND("Inbox";A1)+6;FIND("]";A1;FIND("Inbox";A1))-FIND("Inbox";A1)-6)
 )
```

If there is the word "Inbox" in the text, then you are using three times `MID` to get the three parts out of the text. To find the right start point and the number of characters for `MID` you are using `FIND`.

If you still want to do it in VBA the solution will look similiar, just that you have to use `InStr` instead of `FIND`.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two VBA solutions.  The first is a User Defined Function which extracts the desired segment into the cell in which the formula is located.  The different indexes are defined in the code.

The second is a macro, which processes entries in Column A, starting at A2, and parses the three segments into the adjacent three columns.  Not sure which will work better for you.

They both use Regular Expressions to obtain the different substrings.

Both go into regular modules.

**Function:**

```
Option Explicit
'Returns the three components
'  Index 1 = Time
'  Index 2 = User
'  Index 3 = inbox file
Function ParseInbox(S As String, Index As Long) As Variant
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

'Check that Index is proper
If Index < 1 Or Index > 3 Then
    ParseInbox = CVErr(xlErrNum)
    Exit Function
End If
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^.*((?:\d{2}:\d{2}:)\d{2}).*User\s*\[([^]]+).*Inbox/([^]]+)"
    If .test(S) = True Then
        Set MC = .Execute(S)
        ParseInbox = MC(0).submatches(Index - 1)
    End If
End With
End Function
```

**Macro:**

```
Sub ProcInbox()
'Assumes Data in Column A; starts in A2, and
'   to be split into columns B, C & D
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object
    Dim S As String
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim rRes As Range
    Dim I As Long, J As Long

'Set upper left corner for results
Set rRes = Range("B1")

'Get data
vSrc = Range("a2", Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

'Dim Results Array
    If IsArray(vSrc) Then
        ReDim vRes(1 To UBound(vSrc) + 1, 1 To 3)
    Else
        ReDim vRes(1 To 2, 1 To 3)
    End If
vRes(1, 1) = "Time"
vRes(1, 2) = "User"
vRes(1, 3) = "Inbox File"

 Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
 With RE
    .ignorecase = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = "^.*((?:\d{2}:\d{2}:)\d{2}).*User\s*\[([^]]+).*Inbox/([^]]+)"

    If IsArray(vSrc) Then
        For I = 1 To UBound(vSrc)
            S = vSrc(I, 1)
            If .test(S) = True Then
                Set MC = .Execute(S)
                For J = 0 To 2
                    vRes(I + 1, J + 1) = MC(0).submatches(J)
                Next J
            End If
        Next I
    Else
        S = vSrc
            If .test(S) = True Then
                Set MC = .Execute(S)
                For J = 0 To 2
                    vRes(2, J + 1) = MC(0).submatches(J)
                Next J
            End If
    End If
End With

Set rRes = rRes.Resize(rowsize:=UBound(vRes, 1), columnsize:=UBound(vRes, 2))
rRes.EntireColumn.Clear
rRes = vRes
rRes.EntireColumn.AutoFit
End Sub
```